# Pattern Matching Operation in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I have a tuple to pattern match and do some operation on each element in recursively.

```
[(Int, Char, Int)]
```

I found my way around how to correctly pattern match it to access each element like below:

```
((q1, s, q2):tss)
```

with this I can do some checking operation on each elements within the list. what I intend to to is to recursively perform the same operation on the rest of the elements in the tuple which in this case are tss.

This is part of the code I'm posting here:

```
case ts of 
[] -> False
((q1, s, q2):tss)  | not (q1 `elem` qs) -> False
                   | not (s `elem` qs) -> False
                   | not (q2 `elem` qs) -> False
```

How should I recursively do the same testing on tss?
Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please at least post a complete definition.  What is `qs`?

Comment: do you want to get a list of `Boolean`s or do you want to check if all elements fullfil your property (or do you want to check if at least one does?)

Comment: Best if you just give us a sample input and the desired output for it ;)

Comment: BTW, there's something wrong, `qs` can not be a list of both `Int` and `Char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, write your test function

```
test (q1, s, q2) = q1 `elem` q1List &&
                   s  `elem` sList  &&
                   q2 `elem` q2List
```

with it you can traverse

```
map test tss
```

(use `map`, `filter`, `fold`... as you need).

A direct way to do it may be

```
mapTest [] = []
mapTest (t:tss) = test t: mapTest tss
```

(but is a simple `map`)

A complete example

```
multipleCheck q1List sList q2List tss = traverse tss
  where traverse []      = []
        traverse (t:tss) = check t: traverse tss

        check (q1, s, q2) = q1 `elem` q1List &&
                            s  `elem` sList  &&
                            q2 `elem` q2List

main = print $ multipleCheck [1..5] "abc" [2,3,5] [(1,'b',3), (1,'b',4)]
```

with output

```
[True,False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Function definitions are usually written out in clauses; guarded expressions that return Boolean values can be replaced with just logical expressions:

```
g qs [] = False             -- should be True
g qs ((q1, s, q2):tss)  =
               ( (q1 `elem` qs) &&
                 (s  `elem` qs) &&                 -- the three checks
                 (q2 `elem` qs) && ) && g qs tss   -- and the recursive call
```

We pass `qs` in as a parameter to `g` so that `g` has access to it. Otherwise `qs` would have to be a global, predefined value.

Your base case return value should be True, not False, or else your function will always return False, for any input.

Incidentally, `` g qs tss = all (\(a,b,c)-> all (`elem` qs) [a,b,c]) tss = and (map (\(a,b,c)-> all (`elem` qs) [a,b,c]) tss) ``. Both [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) and [`and`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:and) are so-called ["folds"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), so `g` is as well.

If you wanted to perform same test on each tuple and get a list of results back as an overall result, you just need to change how you combine the recursive results:

```
g qs [] = []              -- False     -- it is a list now, not a Boolean
g qs ((q1, s, q2):tss)  =
               ( (q1 `elem` qs) &&
                 (s  `elem` qs) &&                -- the three checks
                 (q2 `elem` qs) && ) : g qs tss   -- and the recursive call
                         --         ^^^ here
```

And that's the `map` from above, just without the `and`. [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) is also a kind of a "fold".